# Trouble matching pattern at start or end with regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm having difficulty with a Python regex. I want to fine any of N, S, E, W, NB, SB, EB, WB, including at the start or end of the string. My regex easily finds this in the middle, but fails on the start or end.

Can anyone advise what I'm doing wrong with dirPattern i below code sample?

Note: I realize I have some other problems to deal with (e.g. 'W of'), but think I know how to modify the regex for those.

Thanks in advance.

```
import re

nameList = ['Boulder Highway and US 95 NB',  'Boulder Hwy and US 95 SB', 
'Buffalo and Summerlin N', 'Charleston and I-215 W', 'Eastern and I-215 S', 'Flamingo and NB I-15',
'S Buffalo and Summerlin', 'Flamingo and SB I-15', 'Gibson and I-215 EB', 'I-15 at 3.5 miles N of Jean',
'I-15 NB S I-215 (dual)', 'I-15 SB 4.3 mile N of Primm', 'I-15 SB S of Russell', 'I-515 SB at Eastern W',
'I-580 at I-80 N E', 'I-580 at I-80 S W', 'I-80 at E 4TH St Kietzke Ln', 'I-80 East of W McCarran',
'LV Blvd at I-215 S', 'S Buffalo and I-215 W', 'S Decatur and I-215 WB', 'Sahara and I-15 East',
'Sands and Wynn South Gate', 'Silverado Ranch and I-15 (west side)']

dirMap = {'N': 'North', 'S': 'South', 'E': 'East', 'W': 'West'}

dirPattern = re.compile(r'[ ^]([NSEW])B?[ $]')

print('name\tmatch\tdirSting\tdirection')
for name in nameList:
    match = dirPattern.search(name)
    direction = None
    dirString = None
    if match:
        dirString = match.group(1)
        if dirString in dirMap:
            direction = dirMap[dirString]
    print('%s\t%s\t%s\t%s'%(name, match, dirString, direction))
```

Some sample expected output:

> name   match   dirSting    direction
>
> Boulder Highway and US 95 NB       <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f68af836648>   N   North
>
> Boulder Hwy and US 95 SB       <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f68ae836648>   S   South
>
> Buffalo and Summerlin N        <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f68af826648>   N   North
>
> Charleston and I-215 W     <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f68cf836648>   W   West
>
> Flamingo and NB I-15       <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f68af8365d0>   N North
>
> S Buffalo and Summerlin        <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f68aff36648>   S   South
>
> Gibson and I-215 EB        <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f68afa36648>   E   East

However, start or end examples give:

> Boulder Highway and US 95 NB      None    None    None

Comment: `^` and `$` *inside square brackets* doesn't still mean the start/end of the string, you know?

Comment: Jon,Thanks, I did not know, although I was beginning to suspect this.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? You can also use  `direction = dirMap.get(dirString)`, that will return None if there is no matching key in the dict

Comment: Padraic, that's a good tip I was unaware of. Could save a bit of coding. Fundamentally, m question is about extracting the keys N, S, E, W from the sample strings. What I want is N, NB, etc., but only by itself, i.e. either at start followed by space, at end preceded by space, or in middle with space before and after.

Comment: Any reason my question was voted down? I completely realize this is a fairly rookie issue However, I did look around the prior questions, and didn't find anything that helped. Also, I provided working code sample. Seems pretty arbitrary to me.

Comment: How do `NB` etc fit into it? Can you add the output you expect from some of your input?

Comment: What happens with `'S Decatur and I-215 WB'`?

Comment: Padraic, excellent question for 'S Decatur and I-215 WB'. I actually don't know the right answer. I know it is not 'West'. I don't think it's 'South' either. My inclination is 'None' as in no clue, no obvious right answer. Now, how I'll handle that in code, I haven't decided. Might be a few special cases. The list is finite, and known, so this wouldn't bee too bad.

Comment: So you only want string where one of those appear i.e  N or NE but not both?

Comment: Does this give you the correct output? http://pastebin.com/aSbyPECi

Comment: Padraic, I don't want any of the '45 degree' (e.g. NE) directions. Just N, S, E, or W. If a string has multiple of N, S, E, W, either I have to use something more intelligent, or special case. Right now, I get the first one. Which is generally right.

Comment: Padraig, your code seems like it should give what I want. It doesn't quite work as is. I changed one line to: `st = {'N','NB', 'S', 'SB', 'E', 'EB', 'W', 'WB'}` but I'm getting an error from your min line as 'TypeError: min() got an unexpected keyword argument'

Comment: Based on the discussions, I think I have it. First, I realized, I do NOT want the pattern at the end of the string. "Only beginning, or middle. Second, I need to do some more intelliget work, that's my work, for later. Third, the seemingly working regex is `dirPattern = re.compile(r'(?:^| )(?<! at )(?<! of )([NSEW])B? (?!of )')` with the desired match in match.group(1). Thanks to all, particularly Padraig for steering me in the right direction. If Padraig is able to post a working version of his non-regex code, I'll tag that as correct. Even if it does also get the ending case.

Comment: @TyLasky,  can you add the full output you get from your *correct* regex?

Comment: Padraig, see below answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The modified regex in this code does the trick. This includes handling things like 'W of', 'at E', and similar:

```
import re

nameList = ['Boulder Highway and US 95 NB',  'Boulder Hwy and US 95 SB', 
'Buffalo and Summerlin N', 'Charleston and I-215 W', 'Eastern and I-215 S', 'Flamingo and NB I-15',
'S Buffalo and Summerlin', 'Flamingo and SB I-15', 'Gibson and I-215 EB', 'I-15 at 3.5 miles N of Jean',
'I-15 NB S I-215 (dual)', 'I-15 SB 4.3 mile N of Primm', 'I-15 SB S of Russell', 'I-515 SB at Eastern W',
'I-580 at I-80 N E', 'I-580 at I-80 S W', 'I-80 at E 4TH St Kietzke Ln', 'I-80 East of W McCarran',
'LV Blvd at I-215 S', 'S Buffalo and I-215 W', 'S Decatur and I-215 WB', 'Sahara and I-15 East',
'Sands and Wynn South Gate', 'Silverado Ranch and I-15 (west side)']

dirMap = {'N': 'North', 'S': 'South', 'E': 'East', 'W': 'West'}

dirPattern = re.compile(r'(?:^| )(?<! at )(?<! of )([NSEW])B?(?! of )(?: |$)')

print('name\tdirSting\tdirection')
for name in nameList:
    match = dirPattern.search(name)
    direction = None
    dirString = None
    if match:
        dirString = match.group(1)
        direction = dirMap.get(dirString)
    print('> %s\t\t%s\t%s'%(name, dirString, direction))
```

The regex can be understood as follows:

`(?:^| )` start with either beginning of string or a space

`(?<! at )` not preceded by ' at '

`(?<! of )` not preceded by ' of '

`([NSEW])` Any one of 'N', 'S', 'E', 'W' (this will be in match.group(1))

`B?` Optionally followed by 'B' (as in bound)

`(?! of )` not followed by ' at '

`(?: |$)` end with either end of string or a space

Final output is:

> Boulder Highway and US 95 NB      N   North
>
> Boulder Hwy and US 95 SB      S   South
>
> Buffalo and Summerlin N       N   North
>
> Charleston and I-215 W        W   West
>
> Eastern and I-215 S       S   South
>
> Flamingo and NB I-15      N   North
>
> S Buffalo and Summerlin       S   South
>
> Flamingo and SB I-15      S   South
>
> Gibson and I-215 EB       E   East
>
> I-15 at 3.5 miles N of Jean       None    None
>
> I-15 NB S I-215 (dual)        N   North
>
> I-15 SB 4.3 mile N of Primm       S   South
>
> I-15 SB S of Russell      S   South
>
> I-515 SB at Eastern W     S   South
>
> I-580 at I-80 N E     N   North
>
> I-580 at I-80 S W     S   South
>
> I-80 at E 4TH St Kietzke Ln       None    None
>
> I-80 East of W McCarran       None    None
>
> LV Blvd at I-215 S        S   South
>
> S Buffalo and I-215 W     S   South
>
> S Decatur and I-215 WB        S   South
>
> Sahara and I-15 East      None    None
>
> Sands and Wynn South Gate     None    None
>
> Silverado Ranch and I-15 (west side)      None    None

Side note: I decided I don't want the end string case. For this, the regex would be:

`dirPattern = re.compile(r'(?:^| )(?<! at )(?<! of )([NSEW])B? (?!of )')`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```
dirPattern = re.compile(r'(?<!\S)([NSEW])B?(?!\S)')
```

`[ ^]` would match a space or caret symbol. `(?<!\S)` negative lookbehind asserts that the match would be preceded by any bot not a non-space character. `(?!\S)` asserts that he match must not be followed by a non-space character.

Why I used negative lookahead instead of positive means, python's default `re` module won't support `(?<=^| )` .

Comment: Avinash, Thanks for the tip. While I was waiting for answers, I began using lookarounds to handle cases like 'at E 2nd St' or 'W of I-15' (both to be excluded. What I want is N, NB, etc., but only by itself, i.e. either at start followed by space, at end preceded by space, or in middle with space before and after. Your answer may get me there, but right now I'm not sure how.